# msiexec run from innosetup displays help dialog

Tags: inno-setup

I've got the following code as part of my setup script:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#SetupDir}\IronPython-2.7.3.msi"; DestDir: "{app}\Resources"; Components: Centipede; Check: IronPythonNotInstalled

[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/I ""{app}\Resources\IronPython-2.7.3.msi"" /qb"; WorkingDir: "{app}\Resources"; Flags: shellexec; StatusMsg: "Installing IronPython"; Components: Centipede; Check: IronPythonNotInstalled
```

But every time I run the installer, I'm getting the help dialog, as when you run `msiexec` without any parameters.  It's probably just a silly mistake, but I can't see what it is.

The file is getting copied correctly, and the msi is valid (running it from the command line works fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is slightly more complex than I thought: the setup I was running was an old copy of the code.

Due to my environment, I was compiling the installer, pushing it to a (local) web server, then downloading on the test machine, and then running it.

I tried replacing msiexec with a "dump args" tool, and noticed that it still called msiexec.

Testing checksums confirmed it: I was just repeatedly downloading the same version.

The solution here, is to prevent caching of the downloaded installer.